# Tensorflow Error: Incompatible Shapes for Broadcasting

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I am currently developing a program in Tensorflow that reads data 1750 by 1750 pixels. I ran it through a convolutional network:

```
import os
import sys

import tensorflow as tf
import Input

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 100, "hello")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir',     '/Volumes/Machine_Learning_Data',  "hello")

def inputs():
  if not FLAGS.data_dir:
    raise ValueError('Please supply a data_dir')
  data_dir = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'Data')
  images, labels = Input.inputs(data_dir = data_dir, batch_size =     FLAGS.batch_size)
  return images, labels

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape = shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(images, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(images, W, strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], padding =     'SAME')

def max_pool_5x5(images):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(images, ksize = [1, 5, 5, 1], strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], padding = 'SAME')

def forward_propagation(images):
  with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
      W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
      b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
      image_matrix = tf.reshape(images, [-1, 1750, 1750, 1])
      h_conv1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv2d(image_matrix, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
      h_pool1 = max_pool_5x5(h_conv1)

  with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
      W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
      b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
      h_conv2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
      h_pool2 = max_pool_5x5(h_conv2)

  with tf.variable_scope('conv3') as scope:
      W_conv3 = weight_variable([5, 5, 64, 128])
      b_conv3 = bias_variable([128])
      h_conv3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv2d(h_pool2, W_conv3) + b_conv3)
      h_pool3 = max_pool_5x5(h_conv3)

  with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
      W_fc1 = weight_variable([10 * 10 * 128, 256])
      b_fc1 = bias_variable([256])
      h_pool3_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool3, [-1, 10 * 10 * 128])
      h_fc1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h_pool3_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
      keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
      h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
      W_fc2 = weight_variable([256, 4])
      b_fc2 = bias_variable([4])

      y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)
      return y_conv

def error(forward_propagation_results, labels):
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float32)
    mean_squared_error = tf.square(tf.sub(labels, forward_propagation_results))
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(mean_squared_error)
    train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.3).minimize(cost)
    return train

print cost
```

Unfortunately an error has popped up

Incompatible shapes for broadcasting: TensorShape([Dimension(100)]) and TensorShape([Dimension(9187500), Dimension(4)])

and I have not been able to debug this.

What is the issue with the matrix dimensions? The interprer says the error occurred at the tf.sub line.

Edit:

This is the main part of the code where the functions are called.

```
import Input
import Process

import tensorflow as tf


def train():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        images, labels = Process.inputs()

        forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)

        train_loss = Process.error(forward_propgation_results, labels)

        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        sess.run(init)

def main(argv = None):
    train()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on because it seems you're missing the part of the script that calls `error()`.

Comment: Thank you! I will add that soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the following problems:

1. Your `labels` input is a simple 1-dimensional array of label identifiers, but it needs to be one-hot encoded to be a matrix with size `[batch_size, 4]` that's filled with either 1s or 0s.
2. Your max pooling operation needs to have strides that are different from 1 to actually reduce the width and height of the image. So setting `strides=[1, 5, 5, 1]` should work.
3. After fixing that, your max pooling operations don't actually bring down the width/height from 1750 to 10 as you're assuming, but only to 14 (because `1750 / 5 / 5 / 5 == 14`). So you probably want to increase your weight matrix here, but there are other options as well.
4. Is it possible that your images start out with 3 channels? You're assuming grayscale here, so you should either reshape `image_matrix` to have 3 channels, or convert the images to grayscale.

After applying these fixes, both the network output and the labels should have shape `[batch_size, 4]` and you should be able to calculate the difference.

**Edit:** I've adjusted this after discussing the code in the chat below.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first point a bit more? How should I achieve to transform the array into a matrix? I have also looked at the CIFAR-10 Tensorflow code and their implementation uses the 1D array I am using.

Comment: They use a 1D array because [they're using](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L266) the function `tf.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` to calculate the loss function, which is documented here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L266
If you're using that function, then you don't need to perform a one-hot encoding, as it already takes care of it.

Comment: I don't think there's an MSE loss in tensorflow that can do the same for you, so you might have to use the `tf.one_hot` function to perform one-hot encoding yourself: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#one_hot

Comment: What is the difference between 'VALID' padding and 'SAME' padding? In one of the Deep MNIST examples, they used SAME padding.

Comment: Do you mean this example? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#convolution-and-pooling
Note that they are using strides that are different from 1.
SAME and VALID are explained here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#convolution

Comment: I have applied all your changes but another error has popped up. ValueError: input has Dimension(7626434560) elements, which isn't divisible by 12800.

Comment: That error is thrown by one of the reshape operations.
I'm not sure how you managed to get `7626434560` elements in your tensor, that's much larger than `1750 * 1750 * 3 * 100` :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117347/discussion-between-zan-huang-and-ibab).

Answer (score 0):

One_hot labeling add dimension to its input. As an example if the `labels` tensor if of size [batch,1], using `tf.one_hot(batch_labels, depth=2, axis=-1)` returns a [batch,1,2] dimension tensor. For the case of size [batch_size,1] for `labels` tensor the following script can be the solution to get rid of the extra dimension:

`tf.one_hot(tf.squeeze(batch_labels,[1]), depth=2, axis=-1)`

Basically the `labels` tensor must be of size [batch_size,]. The tf.squeeze() function, eliminate specific dimensions. The [1] argument, prompt the function to eliminate the second dimension which is `1`.